# Update existing Google Spreadsheet answers using responses from a Google Form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

So I work for a smaller EMS agency and we're looking for ways to keep track of our inventory and when it's used. Originally we were having our personnel fill out a Google Form with responses on what they used and then going into our inventory spreadsheet and altering it manually.

Is there a way to automate having a Google Form subtract 1 item from our inventory spreadsheet each time the corresponding box is checked on the spreadsheet? Is there an option already on Google that I just haven't found or is it necessary to write a script? And, if the latter, can anyone provide one that would allow this to work?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is best done through a script (Google Apps Script specifically); the only problem is you can only really have 20 open forms.

I can give an overview now and code later:

If it's 1-20 forms (and you're not creating them dynamically (which is also very possible)), then use the `FormApp.openById` for each form and copy in their respective IDs. Then, create a new trigger for each of them (look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))), which is tied to a form (look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forForm(String))). For the spreadsheet, it's even simpler, you just need to get the row with the relevant inventory, you [open by id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) and then use a `for` loop to find the right row. Then use that row number and decrement one

I realize that's a rush and since you seem to be a pretty good cause, you can expect the code at most in 2 days (also I just had to mention [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UON8jjI1GDc) who even integrated it with barcodes).

Comment: Any details would make it easier, esp if there is just a few forms or custom made ones(i.e. new ones very often). Also, the sky is the limit with this, besides just decrementing, you could add a date, the person submitting the form, etc

Comment: So this is a copy of the form our people would be filling out.
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ppvzcqLUor0bqy0bLw0nq5ygh47TBHtBEYCVwawiCbo/viewform

What we're concerned about is the "Supplies Used" section at the bottom of the form. It currently has about 38 items. You mentioned something about 1-20 forms, would this be in excess? You might have noticed I'm not entirely familiar with coding and writing scripts, just a generally good knowledge of getting things to work.